# Identifying where a user is on a web page

Tags: css, position, disqus

I have a new blog. The page in question is [here](http://www.aparkinsonslife.com/Hold_applause.html)

On the left side of the page, I have links to other parts of the blog and social media share buttons.
These links are in a div with position:fixed so it stays in place as the user scrolls through the blog.

I'm using `Disqus` for comments and these links overlay the comments section. I can see two solutions: one is to confine `Disqus` to the right side of the page. I've posted that question on the `Disqus` site. The other solution, for which I need help here, is to find out if there's a way to determine if the user has reached the end of the blog so I can dynamically change the position property so the links scroll upward as the user scans the comments.

Also, if the user scrolls back up through the blog, I want to change the position property back to fixed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just make your comments the width of the post content. That way you can still have the sidebar be fixed and not interfere with the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the vertical offset of the page with javascript `element.scrollTop`.
Next you can get the height of the element above the comments and check with `window.onscroll` the current state wether you can decide if you set the link block `position: absolute;` and add a `top: ;` value or you set `position: fixed;`